# PLS-00306 PLSQL Error while we are compiling package

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Facing PLS-00306 error while compiling the package "PKG_WEB_SERVICES_RITES".

As per my understanding all the fields location and type are correct still showing this error:

```
Error(3603,11): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(3603,57): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PERSON_DETL_REC'
```

Spec:

```
PROCEDURE SP_RETRIVE_PAPAE (p_pa_regn_no      in varchar2,
                         p_pa_uen          in varchar2,
                         O_PA_DETAIL_TBL   out PA_DET_TBL,
                         O_PA_PAST_PMP_TBL out PA_PAST_PMP_TBL,
                         O_LIV_COMP_TBL    out LIV_COMP_TBL,
                         O_PAE_DETL_TBL    out PAE_DETL_TBL,
                         O_Person_detl_tbl out Person_detl_tbl,
                         O_POSTN_DET_TBL   out POSTN_DET_TBL,
                         O_PAST_PMP_TBL    out PAST_PMP_TBL,
                         P_status          out varchar2 /*,
```

Body code :

```
begin
  --Person_detl_rec
  For Person_detl in (
            Select distinct pp.pp_name Persn_Name,
                  pp.pp_id_type IDENT_TYPE,
                  pp.pp_id IDENT_NO,
                  (select pa_regn_no
                     from pa_profile pa
                    where pa_ident_no = pp.pp_id
                      and pa.pa_regn_status_ind = '1') PA_REG_NO,
                  pp.pp_nationality NATIONALITY,
                  to_char(pp.pp_birth_date,
                          'YYYYMMDD') DATE_OF_BIRTH,
                  pp.pp_gender GENDER,
                  pp.tel_no_int_prefix TEL_NO_INT_PREFIX,
                  pp.tel_no_ctry_code TEL_NO_CTRY_CODE,
                  pp.tel_no TEL_NO,
                  pp.mobile_no_int_prefix PA_MOBILE_NO_INT_PREFIX,
                  pp.mobile_no_ctry_code PA_MOBILE_NO_CTRY_CODE,
                  pp.mobile_no PA_MOBILE_NO,
                  pp.email_addr_local_part PA_EMAIL_ADDR_LOCAL_PART,
                  pp.email_addr_at_sign PA_EMAIL_ADDR_AT_SIGN,
                  pp.email_addr_domain PA_EMAIL_ADDR_DOMAIN,
                  pp.pp_postal_code POSTAL_CODE,
                  pp.pp_blkhse_no BLOCK_NO,
                  (select street_name
                     from m_street
                    where street_key =
                          pp.pp_street_key) STREET_NAME,
                  pp.pp_level_no LEVEL_NO,
                  pp.pp_unit_no UNIT_NO,
                  pp.pp_bldg_name BUILDNG_NAME,
                  pp.pp_addr_type ADDR_TYPE,
                  pp.alt_addr_type ALT_ADDR_TYPE,
                  pp.pp_pref_mode_comm PREF_MODE_OF_COMM,
                  to_char(pp.pp_addr_change,
                          'YYYYMMDD') ADDR_CHG_DATE

            from people_profile pp, v_Retrieve_Papae v
           where v.NRIC_NO = pp.pp_id
             and V.UEN_NO = p_pa_uen
          -- and upper(p.pa_regn_no) = upper(p_pa_regn_no)
          -- and p.pa_regn_no = p_pa_regn_no
        ) 
    loop
    begin
      O_Person_detl_tbl.Extend;
      O_Person_detl_tbl(O_Person_detl_tbl.Count) := Person_detl_rec(
                Person_detl.Persn_Name,
                Person_detl.Ident_Type,
                Person_detl.Ident_No,
                Person_detl.Pa_Reg_No,
                Person_detl.Nationality,
                Person_detl.Date_Of_Birth,
                Person_detl.Gender,
                Person_detl.Tel_No_Int_Prefix,
                Person_detl.Tel_No_Ctry_Code,
                Person_detl.Tel_No,
                Person_detl.Pa_Mobile_No_Int_Prefix,
                Person_detl.Pa_Mobile_No_Ctry_Code,
                Person_detl.Pa_Mobile_No,
                Person_detl.Pa_Email_Addr_Local_Part,
                Person_detl.Pa_Email_Addr_At_Sign,
                Person_detl.Pa_Email_Addr_Domain,
                Person_detl.Postal_Code,
                Person_detl.Block_No,
                Person_detl.Street_Name,
                Person_detl.Level_No,
                Person_detl.Unit_No,
                Person_detl.Buildng_Name,
                Person_detl.Addr_Type,
                Person_detl.Alt_Addr_Type,
                Person_detl.Pref_Mode_Of_Comm,
                Person_detl.Addr_Chg_Date,
                p_pa_uen);

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        P_status := SQLERRM;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Person_detl_rec  ' || SQLERRM);
    END;

  end loop;
  if O_Person_detl_tbl.count > 0 then
    p_status := 'TRUE';
  end if;
  /*open oc_result_cursor_4 for
  select * from table(O_Person_detl_tbl);*/
end;
```

Comment: Saying that "As per my understanding all the fields location and type are correct" & regarding the fact that Oracle disagrees, I - kind of - trust Oracle rather than you :)

Comment: The error message is very confident that you are using person_detl_rec with the wrong number of arguments. If this is a type you’ve created in the DB then you can desc it with sq*plus to get the attributes it has, if it’s part of this package then you can just look at it there. Line up the definition against where you assigning the attributes values and see where the difference is.